# Excel Macro or VBA for making selected range values absolute

Tags: excel, vba

Can anybody help me out in making all values of my selected range values Absolute (or applying absolute formula on each cell in a range) by single button using Excel VBA?

```
   A              B               C
5.119999886  -13.06999969   -13.14000034
-5.76999998  -12.52000046   -12.78999996
-5.88000011  -13.69999981   -14.13000011
5.46999979   -12.61999989   -12.48999977
```

Comment: Not exactly VBA, but if required can be recorded, select your Data Range, press Ctrl H (Replace), in Find what add " - " sign and replace all. This will remove the negative sign from all numbers and it will become absolute.

Comment: Worked well but it took time just because i have 6 columns & 150,000 rows, anyhow thank you very much as it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:F10")
    rng.Replace what:="-", lookat:=xlPart, replacement:=""
End Sub
```

Comment: Then replace `Set rng = Range("A1:F10")` with `Set rng = Selection`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly VBA, but if required can be recorded.

Select your Data Range, press Ctrl H (Replace), in Find what add " - " sign and replace all. This will remove the negative sign from all numbers and it will become absolute.

Note: As mentioned in comment that OP agrees that this works for him, hence posting as an answer.

Comment: Great solution! Simple and quick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub MakeAbsolute()

        Dim c As Range
        Dim rngToAbs As Range

        'Set the worksheet name and range appropriately
        Set rngToAbs = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C2")

        For Each c In rngToAbs
                c.Value = Abs(c.Value)
        Next c

End Sub
```

You need to change `Sheet1` to your worksheet name and `A1:C2` to whatever range of cells you want to take the absolute value of.

Hopefully the code is simple enough to understand, but the basic idea is that we will declare a specific range, loop through each cell in that range, and change the value of that cell to be the absolute value by applying the `Abs` function.

Comment: Thank you it worked good but i don't want to fix the range or sheet name, i want to use it any where in my workbook by just selecting my desired range & running a Macro/VBA Code.