# Make all active cells in a specific Column to its Absolute Value

Tags: excel, vba

Can you help me correct my VBA codes. I want to convert the values of Column U until the active row to Absolute Values meaning to remove the negative amounts.
Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub MakeColumnsAbsoluteValue()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rngToAbs As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MJEBlackline")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows, Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngToAbs = Range("U5:U" & LastRow)

    For Each c In rngToAbs
        c.Value = Abs(c.Value)

    Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give you any error ?

Comment: You may want to include your `sht` variable in this line to fully qualify the range. `Set rngToAbs = sht.Range("U5:U" & LastRow)`

Comment: Depending on your data, you might get a problem with the `Abs`-Function. You get an Runtime error 13 (type mismatch) if one of your cell contains a string. Use the `IsNumeric`-function to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
Sub MakeColumnsAbsoluteValue()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rngToAbs As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MJEBlackline")
With sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngToAbs = .Range("U5:U" & LastRow)
    rngToAbs.Value = .Evaluate("=abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & ")")
End With

End Sub
```

Or even ([inspired through @GarysStudent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746549/9758194)):

```
Sub MakeColumnsAbsoluteValue()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rngToAbs As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MJEBlackline")
With sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngToAbs = .Range("U5:U" & LastRow)
    rngToAbs.Replace what:="-", lookat:=xlPart, replacement:=""
End With

End Sub
```

This would both convert the whole range in one go. Assuming that's what you meant with:

> *"I want to convert the values of Column U until the active row..."*

Answer (score 3):

Problem with line `LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows, Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row`

Use of `,` instead of `.` and not specifying the sheet reference in `rngToAbs`

**Try:**

```
Sub MakeColumnsAbsoluteValue()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rngToAbs As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FF")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "U").End(xlUp).row
    Set rngToAbs = sht.Range("U5:U" & LastRow)

    For Each c In rngToAbs
        c.Value = Abs(c.Value)

    Next c


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeColumnsAbsoluteValue()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rngToAbs As Range, c As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim arr() As Variant

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MJEBlackline")
    x = 0

    With sht

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngToAbs = .Range("U5:U" & LastRow)

        'Loop range and create an array including all abs values
        For Each c In rngToAbs
            ReDim Preserve arr(x)
            arr(x) = Abs(c.Value)
            x = x + 1
        Next c

        'Paste the values of the array at once instead of pasting values one by one
        .Range("U5:U" & LastRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

    End With

End Sub
```